# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler does not fire when we select already selected cells

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

I'm trying to handle cell(s) selection change event. And create a custom formula.

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler` serves this. But it gets fired only when the new selected cell(s) is different than already selected cell(s).

```
Excel.Workbook workbook;
Workbook.SheetSelectionChange += Events_SheetSelectionChange;

public void Events_SheetSelectionChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Excel object model doesn't provide any event if you click on the same cell. The best what you could do is to use Windows API function to handle mouse clicks. But that requires a good knowledge of Windows API functions.

You may find a similar post helpful, see [action when a cell is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113275/action-when-a-cell-is-clicked) for more information.